# find and replace multiple expressions

Tags: replace, text-editor

I have two txt files

the first file structure

```
text1|text2
```

the seconde file structure is

```
text2|text3
```

Now I want to replace all the text2 of the first file with the text3 of the seconde file , and the condition must be text2 of the first file muchs with the text2 of the seconde file

Example

First File:

```
sfaxsy|contact@syfax.net
user2|admin@syfax.net
```

Seconde file:

```
admin@syfax.net|verified
contact@syfax.net|unverified
```

Final File :

```
sfaxsy|unverified
user2|verified
```

I have over 3k lines

Thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you have shell scripting available to you. This script solves it.

```
#!/bin/sh
for line in `cat file1`; do
    pt1=`echo $line | cut -f 1 -d '|'`
    key=`echo $line | cut -f 2 -d '|'`
    pt2=`grep "${key}" file2 | cut -f 2 -d '|'`
    echo "$pt1|$pt2" >> file3
done
```

Comment: I tried your code @JoshOfAllTrades , it words , but there are some text2 from the file1 , that are not on the file2 , so it paste duplicates and some lines that I don't understand , anyway it works a bit , thanks for the help , if you can help me to fix this , it will be a pleasure

Comment: Sorry it was my fault your script is working , I will work with it !